# How to get back the Bookmark Toolbar in Firefox 4?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks

Somehow I have lost the bookmark toolbar in Firefox 4.

When I click on the menu *bookmarks*, *bookmark toolbar*, I see all my links there, but it's not showing up "as a bar" on the top menu.

Also, when I right click on the top menu, it shows "Bookmarks Toolbar" and it DOES have a check next to it.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to get this back?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any addons you use? Try disabling them and making sure it's still checked.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @slhck - i added a screenshot

Comment: If you go to Customise, is "Bookmark Toolbar Items" in there?

Comment: @sblair - no its not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click, choose *Customize*, click *Restore Default Set*.

Answer (score 0):

Toggle the "Bookmark Toolbar" check. If that doesn't bring it back, then you might try reinstalling Firefox, and choose an option to import stuff from the old install. It could be that nothing is wrong with your settings, but that the configuration is corrupt somehow.

Answer (score -1):

Right click on toolbar (somewhere next to address bar) and enable "Bookmark Toolbar" and bookmark toolbar is enabled.That's all.

Comment: my question states, when i right click on the top menu it "DOES" have it checked.